# Write an array list of type ArrayList<String[]> to file

Tags: file, arraylist, binary, filestream

Im trying to write an array list to a file, i have a method that returns in the type:

```
ArrayList<String[]>
```

In a separate method i want to write what the previous method returns to a file. How would i go about doing this? A binary file rather than a text file?

thank you

Comment: ArrayList is outdated, do you have the option to use lists?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is outdated and I should use List if I were you.
What you want can be achieved with following method:

```
public void WriteTextToFile(List<String[]> TextToFile)
{
    string textToWrite = String.Empty;
    foreach(string[] array in TextToFile)
    {
        foreach(string text in array)
        {
            textToWrite += text;
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TextFile.txt", textToWrite);
}
```

Use your method here to call the above method:

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    List<String[]> text = new List<String[]>();
    //Add data to text variable here
    ...
    ...
    WriteTextToFile(text);
}
```

I used `List<String[]>` in `YourMethod` as you can see.

I will make this code compatibel with your code, if you give me your existing method...